# HTML escaping does not behave the same if angular-translate is used as directive (instead of as a filter)

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

angular-translate - version: 2.8, angular-version 1.3.5

Translation-key `MyKey` contains `<i>Text</i>`

Given snippet:

```
<p translate="MyKey"></p>
<p translate="{{'MyKey'}}"></p>
<p><translate>MyKey</translate></p>
<p>{{'MyKey' | translate}}</p>
```

Results in:

```
Text          --> italic, why is it not escaped?
Text          --> italic, why is it not escaped?
Text          --> italic, why is it not escaped?
<i>Text</i>   --> I expect it that way
```

Why does the translate-filter escapes as expected, but as directive it fails to escape anything?

I also tampered around with `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');`, doesn't do any difference to the above example.

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS applications, the filter's output will be escaped always. This is done automatically and is not under control of the filter function itself. In the opposite, the directive has the complete control about which and how information will be appended/ removed/ and so on.

```
// ensure angular-sanitize.js is present
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
```

Sanitization is not escaping! Instead of escaping everything, it checks for valid (and secure) string (html, javascript, css). If it is valid, it will use the actual input. Otherwise it will be rejected.

I've made an overview matrix of directive, filter and escape/sanitization settings in angular-translate. The case is an ongoing issue with UTF-8 characters, but I think you will get it: http://plnkr.co/edit/8BHONOjhsxBxxO9oVYOK?p=preview

Disclaimer: I'm co-maintaining angular-translate.